# What is the definition of the $SU(3)$ group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, lie-groups

The definition of the $SU(2)$ group is :

$$
SU(2):=\left\{ \pmatrix{\alpha & - \overline{\beta} \\ \beta &\overline{\alpha} } : \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}, |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1 \right\}
$$

What is the equivalent definition for $SU(3)$?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group), the  Gell-Mann matrices are the $SU(3)$ analog of the Pauli matrices for $SU(2)$. So no "equivalent" definition, but like the general definition for $SU(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $3×3$ matrices $U$ instead of $2×2$, with the same conditions: $U^*=U^{-1}$ and $\operatorname{det}U=1$.

Comment: Still, it is hard to find an exact and simplified representation. I don't suppose you have a link to the definition?

Comment: I looked at @DietrichBurde's link

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(3)) is the relevant subheading within @DietrichBurde's link. This answer is pretty simple, if it's not an adequate answer for you, then you should explain more clearly what you are asking.